# node.js zip utilities that works with node-webkit?

Tags: zip, node-webkit

Has anyone been able to successfully create a zip file that can be read by node-webkit using any of the node.js zip utility? 
I have tried node-zip, admzip, node-archiever, etc. but havent' had much luck. For one reason or another, none of the files can be read by node-webkit  *(and sometimes by, say, winzip as well)*

Comment: Are you creating the zip using a standard zip utility, say from the desktop, then wanting to read via a node-webkit app or is the zip being created by node-webkit, perhaps saved, then read again by node-webkit? Just want to make sure I understand the scenario correctly.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the posting. The zip is going to be read by node-webkit itself. I am trying to zip my project directory to, say, app.nw, so that it can run with node-webkit as 'nw app.nw'.

Comment: I see, that would reduce a step in the build process if Node could do it via a grunt task or something.  I'm surprised none of those utilities are working well for you - I wonder if you can take it up with their authors on Github describing what you are experiencing and then they may have a way to help you diagnose the problem.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: thanks. i am trying grunt as I speak. I tried raising an issue to admzip but not the others. i think i'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to package your app with the tools provided by the Yeoman Generator: https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-node-webkit

```
$ npm install -g yo
$ npm install -g generator-node-webkit
$ yo node-webkit
```

Then, put your code inside the **app** folder and run one of these:

```
grunt dist-mac
grunt dist-win
grunt dist-linux
```

This will package your app and leave the executable on the **dist** folder.